# Select default value from one table by joining itself

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example I have one table and 3 **NOT NULL** columns in t_shops: id, name, locale. Locale column has default value as " " empty string.  I need to select default value if where statement doesnt match **AND** I need to do this by joining same table and passing to COALESCE function something like this. I know how to do this by COALESCE in WHERE clause and by UNION ALL but i need it by joining

```
SELECT COALESCE(arg1.locale, 'default') currentLocale
    ,A.*
FROM t_product_attrs A
INNER t_product_attrs arg1
    ON A.locale = arg1.locale
        AND A.product_id = arg1.product_id
WHERE arg1.locale = 'not what i have in DB'
    AND arg1.product_id = 100101
```

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: If you are using MsSql, you could also combine with NULLIF(arg1.locale, ' ')

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(arg1.locale, 'default') as currentLocale, A.*
FROM t_product_attrs A INNER
     t_product_attrs arg1
     ON A.locale = arg1.locale AND
        A.product_id = arg1.product_id  AND
        arg1.locale = 'not what i have in DB' AND
        arg1.product_id = 100101;
```